# Is a paired t-test appropriate for this data?

Tags: paired-data

I have 3 sites, that have been measured annually for abundance of species A and abundance of species B. Do I use a paired t-test to see if species A is having an impact on species B abundance?

Answer (score 0):

No - a paired t-test would test for a difference in the abundance of species A and species B.

You could use a regression to test for an effect of species A abundance on species B abundance.  Species B abundance would be your response, and Species A abundance would be your predictor.

As your response is count data, you might want to use a generalized linear model, with a poisson distribution.

You might also want to think about using a mixed effects model, and including site, and maybe year, as random effects.